# SQLite concatenate string does not work. Gives near "||": syntax error

Tags: sqlite

This is my code I run in DB Browser for SQLite.
The line with || is not working.

```
/* Who are my highest performing employees? */
SELECT      e.EmployeeID,
            e.TitleOfCourtesy,
            e.FirstName,
            e.LastName,
            e.FirstName || ‘ ’ || e.LastName AS Name,
            e.Title,
            COUNT(o.OrderId) AS NumberOrders
FROM Employees e
JOIN Orders o
        ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
GROUP BY e.EmployeeID
ORDER BY NumberOrders DESC
```

The result I got is this:

```
-- At line 1:
/* Who are my highest performing employees? */
SELECT      e.EmployeeID,
            e.TitleOfCourtesy,
            e.FirstName,
            e.LastName,
            e.FirstName || e.LastName AS Name,
            e.FirstName || ‘ ’ ||
-- Result: near "||": syntax error
```

I have read articles that `string1 || '' || string2` works for SQLite. But I cannot understand why it does not work.

Please help!

Comment: Try `(e.FirstName || ‘ ’ || e.LastName) AS Name,`

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between using the ‘ and ' whereas you should be using the later one in SQL.
Try using the query below:

```
SELECT  e.EmployeeID,
        e.TitleOfCourtesy,
        e.FirstName,
        e.LastName,
        e.FirstName || ' ' || e.LastName AS Name,
        e.Title,
        COUNT(o.OrderId) AS NumberOrders
        FROM Employees e
        JOIN Orders o
        ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
        GROUP BY e.EmployeeID
        ORDER BY NumberOrders DESC
```

Comment: Hi ajay, I managed to solve my problem. You are right about the quotes that it should not look like that. I posted my answer up there. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem. It was a silly mistake!

I have identified the problem :
I was using Chinese Microsoft Pinyin keyboard so that typing of single quotes turned into weird colour and shape. (I was typing chinese at the other places.)

I solved it with this method:
I solved it by changing back the keyboard to US keyboard and retype the quotes. 
It works!